# How create a todo list with octobercms?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios, octobercms

I watched [this tutorial](https://watch-learn.com/series/vue-2-and-october-cms-todo-app) to create a simple API and use it with VueJS.

I do not have any problem with fetching data but when I try to create a new Todo I get this error:

> OPTIONS http://localhost/vue-test/api/add-todo2 404 (Not Found)
>   Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/vue-test/api/add-todo2' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

My `.htaccess` configuration:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

This is my JavaScript method:

```
addTodo(todo) {
    this.todos.push(todo);

    axios.post('http://localhost/vue-test/api/add-todo2', todo)
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

And this is my server code:

```
Route::post('/api/add-todo', function (Request $request) {
    $data = $request->input();
    Todo::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'body' => $data['body'],
    'status' => $data['status']
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. My problem fixed by adding the following lines to the `.htaccess` file:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, cache-control"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

For more details, you can check [this article](https://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/).